# Why does ServletContext.addListener use generic type?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlet-3.0, generic-programming

Servlet API 3.0 provide the `addListener` method for `ServletContext`

```
<T extends EventListener> void addListener(T t);
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#addListener-T- .

Why isn't this method defined as:

```
void addListener(EventListener listener);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that's because `EventListener` is a *tagging* interface only - it doesn't have any methods, so having `void addListener(EventListener listener);` would be nonsense code - like "give me something that has no methods I can call".

With declaring this as `<T extends EventListener> void addListener(T t);` it's clear to the implementor, that *something more* than simply an `EventListener` is needed here.